# Define a XML datasource and import it to the grails app in bootstrap stage

Tags: xml, grails

my aim is to import some certain data to the database of a Grails app in the bootstrap stage. Say defaultData.xml. Where can I configure this xml datasource's path, so that I don't need to worry about the tomcat deployment later? What is the most common way to implement this function in Grails?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the xml file in `grails-app/conf`.  The file will be bundled up into a war if you build one.  In BootStrap.groovy, you can refer to the file with `class.getResource("defaultData.xml")`, which will access the file in both a regular development environment and a war deployment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried to write some code in bootstrap.groovy like this:   `def defaultDataFileStream = this.class.getResourceAsStream("defaultData.xml")
      def allData = new XmlSlurper().parse(defaultDataFileStream)` it says that the source file can not be found..

Comment: Works for me.  Does it fail in a dev environment, a deployed warfile, or both?

Comment: Hi. What if I would like to put the logic code into service? In my grails service. I injected init service in bootstrap.groovy. The paths I specify in my conf folder are not found. Is there any better way to do so? Many thanks.